# Bootstrap slider formatter use html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

How to modify tooltip in bootstrap slider with some tag?

example :

```
  let customSlide = creditSliderElement.slider({
      formatter: function (value) {
          return '<h3>' + value + '</h3>';
      }
  });
```

It is now showing like a string. When use `$.parseHTML( '<h3>' + value + '</h3>')` showed `[object HTMLHeadingElement]`, how to customize tool tip format in bootstrap slider ?

Comment: From the look of the output `creditlimit` is a reference to a `Hx` element. As such try `return '<h3>' + creditlimit.innerHTML + '</h3>'`

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Did you try my suggestion above?

Comment: yes, it's not make sense, value this is some digit, like 33 and 33.innerHTML return undefined

Comment: Can you edit the question to show where `creditlimit` is defined, and what HTML element it refers to.

Comment: call back function contain parameter `value` (current value from slider, digit), looks `formatter` in  bootstrap slider